# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil - when creating a UIImage

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm getting the following Error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

*Please do not mark this as a duplicate, I know what Optionals and unwrapping them are.*

1. This error is appearing on line 9.
2. The error happens when the app is running and I perform a segue.

Code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var rewardVideoImage: UIImageView!

 let arrayOfPhotos = ["photo1", "photo2", "photo3"]
 var randomImageIndex : Int = 0

 func selectImage() {
    randomImageIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    rewardVideoImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfPhotos[randomImageIndex])
    print(randomImageIndex)
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectImage()
 }
```

Comment: Unwrap `UIImage(named: arrayOfPhotos[randomImageIndex])` with an `if let` to see if the image exists.

Comment: I think `rewardVideoImage` is nil, are you sure it's connected properly?

Comment: @user770 image property is optional so there is no need to unwrap the result. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image

Comment: I don't know what doing `if let` is called. Maybe not "unwrapping", but clearly the image name used is incorrect, or something like that. And I'm trying to have the OP check that.

Comment: I am saying that setting the property to nil won't throw an error

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Try removing re-importing the photos, and checking they are named correctly and case-sensitive.

Comment: Only reason is `rewardVideoImage` is `nil` here, either you missed connecting from `UIStoryboard` or it is taking wrong reference. Remove the outlet of `rewardVideoImage` and connect it again on `UIStoryboard` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

`arc4Random` isn't the problem here, it's your `IBOutlet` as a nil image wouldn't cause a crash.

`rewardVideoImage` is nil, you need to connect it in your storyboard.

Comment: AFAIK, attempting to access a property that is not connected to storyboard doesn't even build.

Comment: @user770 It does if it's an implicitly unwrapped optional, and it will crash with this exact error.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. So my suggestion to use `if let` wasn't so off after all :)

Comment: @JamesP It is already connected to the storyboard

Comment: @Callum9966 Maybe you should show how you create and push the viewController. From the code you've shown `rewardVideoImage` being nil is the only explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here can cause optional issue as far as I think:

1. Make sure you have images named "photo1", "photo2", "photo3" in your assets catalogue.
2. Make sure your storyboard has proper reference to your `UIImageView`

Comment: All double checked and are fine.